# regex and python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
myString = "123ABC,'2009-12-23T23:45:58.544-04:00'"
```

I want to extract the "T" character from the Timestamp, ie change it to:

```
"123ABC,'2009-12-23 23:45:58.544-04:00'"
```

I am trying this:

```
newString = re.sub('(?:\-\d{2})T(?:\d{2}\:)', ' ', myString)
```

BUT, the returned string is:

```
"123ABC,'2009-12 45:58.544-04:00'"
```

The "non capturing groups" don't appear to be "non capturing", and it's removing everything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just replace?

Comment: Or, if you can't replace, something like `''.join(myString.split('T'))`?

Comment: This question is vastly underspecified. Where did the timestamp come from in the first place? Why don't you want the T? Are you sure the timestamp will always be in that locale? What if it isn't?

Comment: The group doesn't capture, but the pattern still does.

Comment: Yep, I deliberately simplified this question. I have control over the locale, this isn't as simple as it seems, so replace/split won't work because it's a HUGE string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds (*positive lookbehind and -ahead*):

```
(?<=\d)T(?=\d)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wR4mA3/1).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re
myString = "123ABC,'2009-12-23T23:45:58.544-04:00'"
rx = r'(?<=\d)T(?=\d)'
# match a T surrounded by digits

new_string = re.sub(rx, ' ', myString)
print new_string
# 123ABC,'2009-12-23 23:45:58.544-04:00'
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/lNbPBb).

Comment: This worked, but I need it to be more specific... to minimize the chance of matching other text data... I realize that this solution isn't perfect, but good enough for now... Thanks... The "look around" helped... need to polish up on my regex skillz
newString = re.sub('(?<=\-\d{2})T(?=\d{2}\:)', ' ', myString)...

Comment: @Calamari: Note that lookarounds in Python `re` are fixed witdth. Capturing groups are much more flexible. Use `re.sub(r'(-\d{2})T(\d{2}:)', r'\1 \2', myString)`. And use raw string literals when defining regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

`regex` seems a bit of an overkill:

```
mystring.replace("T"," ")
```

Comment: Come on... what if `myString = "123RST,'2009-12-23T23:45:58.544-04:00'"`?

Comment: @dot.Py How about `" ".join(s.rsplit("T", 1))` then? Also works if there is a `T` in the first part, assuming that the date is always the last part.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use capturing groups, unanchored lookbehinds are costly in terms of regex performance:

```
(\d)T(\d)
```

And replace with `r'\1 \2'` replacement pattern containing backreferences to the digit before and after `T`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP5mR1/1)

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/qY0Enq):

```
import re
s = "123ABC,'2009-12-23T23:45:58.544-04:00'"
reg = re.compile(r'(\d)T(\d)')
s = reg.sub(r'\1 \2', s)
print(s)
```

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'(-\d{2})T(\d{2}:)', r'\1 \2', s)` if you need to precise the content.

Answer (score 0):

That `T` is trapped in between numbers and will always be alone on the right. You could use a `rsplit` and `join`:

```
myString = "123ABC,'2009-12-23T23:45:58.544-04:00'"
s = ' '.join(myString.rsplit('T', maxsplit=1))
print(s)
# "123ABC,'2009-12-23 23:45:58.544-04:00'"
```

Trying this on a leading `T` somewhere in the string:

```
myString = "123ATC,'2009-12-23T23:45:58.544-04:00'"
s = ' '.join(myString.rsplit('T', maxsplit=1))
print(s)
# "123ATC,'2009-12-23 23:45:58.544-04:00'"
```